# How to give out user input error messages in rasa?

Tags: chatbot, rasa

how to give out error messages if a user input doesn’t match any intents.
Example: I am making a restaurant finding rasa bot, so I was thinking of making the rasa bot ask location of where the user is looking for a restaurant, So if there are no restaurants in location entered by the user how to return “sorry there are no restaurants in this location” message.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create this behaviour using a rule and a slot. For example:

```
- rule: nothing found
  condition:
  - slot_was_set:
    - restaurant_found: false
  steps:
  - action: utter_no_restaurants_found
```

You'll need to create a boolean slot for `restaurant_found` and set this to false or true in a custom action.

```
slots:
  restaurant_found:
    type: bool
```

The [custom action](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/custom-actions) would look something like this (you need to add the "successful" condition, and whatever your code does to search for a restaurant.)

```
class RestaurantSearchAction(Action):

    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "restaurant_search"

    async def run(
        self, dispatcher, tracker: Tracker, domain: Dict[Text, Any],
    ) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:
        # search for restaurant with your
        # custom code here. You can get entities
        # from the tracker like so: tracker.get_latest_entity_values
        if <successful>:
            return [SlotSet(restaurant_found, True)]
        else:
            return [SlotSet(restaurant_found, False)]
```